# Авокадо: фрукт или овощ?

Tags: терминология

Тут, помнится, как-то обсуждали тему фруктов и овощей. А вот меня интересует авокадо. Как его называть: фруктом или овощем? Выглядит как фрукт, продается в отделе фруктов, но не сочный и не сладкий (а фрукты определяются как "сочне и сладкие плоды, растущие не деревьях и кустарниках).
Заранее благодарю за ваше мнение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ИНФОРМАЦИЯ ИЗ ИНТЕРНЕТА

"И по внешнему виду, и по вкусу, и даже по химическому составу авокадо ближе к овощам, но все же это – натуральный фрукт с большой косточкой внутри.Растет на деревьях до 20 м высотой.

Но во Вьетнаме этот ароматный и сладкий фрукт – овощ. Его используют в больших количествах в супах и для приготовления мясных и рыбных блюд.

Авокадо считается типично мексиканским фруктом, известным еще со времен ацтеков.Hазывают авокадо по разному: и «лесное масло», из-за нежной и мягкой, как масло, мякоти у спелого плода, и «аллигаторова груша», за зеленый, «крокодиловый» цвет кожуры и формy плода. Кстати, у ацтеков название авокадо – «ahuacatl» – означало «яичко», и у них оно считалось афродизиаком. А названием «авокадо» мы обязаны испанцам, которые первыми из европейцев открыли этот фрукт".

http://www.domashniy.ru/article/eda/enciklopediya/avokado_-_eto_frukt.html

Comment: Сладкий? 0_0 )))